# How to order a Buildingnumber chronological in MS SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

Hello i need to order a list of building in chronological order. Here is an example

```
select building from adress order by building asc
```

Result:

```
Emil
G1
G10
G2
G3
G4
G5
```

What i need is this order:

```
Emil
G1
G2
G3
G4
G5
G10
```

is this possible? Or should i create a prioritylist where i can order it like the priority?

Comment: is there any specific format of column 'Building'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have always a letter before the number.

In this way I order before about your letter (A, B, C... G and so on) and after by number of building.

Try this:

```
SELECT building
FROM address
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(building, 1, 1), CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(building, 2, 100))
```

**EDIT**

You can use `PATINDEX` function with regular expression (as adviced [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/10/14/sql-server-find-first-non-numeric-character-from-string/))

```
SELECT building
FROM address
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(building, 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', building) - 1), 
CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(building, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', building), 100))
```

Comment: Only if the alpha component is fixed

Comment: @daniele3004: Yes, In head of my answer I write: "I suppose you have always a letter before the number."

Comment: thanks for your answer, what can i do when a building like "emil" has a number,too. for an example : "emil. 42"

Comment: i am getting an error because i cant convert the name "emil. 24" to int with your substring

Comment: Dear, so you have a variable part of letter before number. So I think as can I change my solution for you. Please when you wirte a question explicit these cases, because your result set has only Gxx

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic:-)

My advice, which is what I do. 
Each table has a unique id automatically.

To order the fields using a numerator of order which is usually the id of the table if your data is inserted in order.

Otherwise you manage a numerator in a separate column of the table.

If your "G" component is dynamic use this solution

```
SELECT building
FROM address
ORDER BY ID_COLUMN_ORDER
```

otherwise if your component "G" is fixed use this

```
SELECT building
FROM address
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(building, 1, 1), CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(building, 2, 100))
```